# Template Metaprogramming for concatenation of compile-time sequences

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

So I've been experimenting a bit with compile-time sequences in c++ with my own sequence classes, but I've run into a problem into eager template instantiation, or at least I think that's what it is.

```
template <typename SeqA, typename SeqB, int... Items>
class Concat 
    : public std::conditional<SeqA::is_empty() && SeqB::is_empty(),
                 Seq<Items...>, 
                 typename std::conditional<SeqA::is_empty(),
                     typename Concat<SeqA, typename SeqB::Tail, Items..., SeqB::Head>::type, 
                     typename Concat<typename SeqA::Tail, SeqB, Items..., SeqA::Head>::type
                 >::type
              >
{
};
```

I get an error message from the compiler stating that

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Concat<Seq<2, 4, 6, 8, 10>, Seq<>, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9>’:
main.cpp:75:7:   recursively instantiated from ‘Concat<Seq<2, 4, 6, 8, 10>, Seq<3, 5, 7, 9>, 1>’
main.cpp:75:7:   instantiated from ‘Concat<Seq<2, 4, 6, 8, 10>, Seq<1, 3, 5, 7, 9> >’
main.cpp:99:52:   instantiated from here
main.cpp:75:7: error: no type named ‘Tail’ in ‘class Seq<>’
...
```

The concat class works by grabbing an item out of the first non-empty sequence and appending it to it's own variadic arguments. When both sets are empty it returns a Set with elements as the sequence, but the error message gives me the feeling that the compiler will instantiate both parts of the std::conditional regardless of the truth-value. Is there a way around this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is way overcomplicated. Here's how I would have written `Concat`:

```
template <int...> class Seq;
template <typename SeqA, typename SeqB> class Concat;
template <int... Ints1, int... Ints2>
class Concat<Seq<Ints1...>, Seq<Ints2...>>
{
    using type = Seq<Ints1..., Ints2...>;
};
```

---

Yes, `std::conditional` needs to evaluate all of its parameters; no short-circuiting happens. This can be worked around with another layer of indirection, as usual in programming.

Comment: That is a much better implementation than what I had in mind.